# Cannot install npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, redux, nodist

Today I tried to install redux and I got bellow error

Having said that it's not only happening for redux.

```
C:\FE-Proj-Templates\webpack>npm i -D redux
npm WARN package.json ozone@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json ozone@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ozone@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\v-x64\\4.5.0\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\No
dist\\npmv\\2.15.9\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-D" "redux"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.21 does not satisfy it siblings' peerDependenci
es requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer babel-loader@6.2.5 wants webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 wants webpack@^1.9.11
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer sass-loader@4.0.0 wants webpack@^1.12.6 || ^2.1.0 beta
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.0.0-beta wants webpack@>=2.0.3-beta <3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer html-webpack-plugin@2.22.0 wants webpack@*

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\FE-Proj-Templates\webpack\npm-debug.log
```

I am using nodist node 4.5.0 and I was able to install packages few days ago.

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by installing and using npm3

```
npm install -g npm3
```